# Is there a way to get screen to return a session id or pid?

Tags: perl, return-value, gnu-screen

Is there a way to get screen to echo back the session id when it creates a new window?

I am working on script in perl and I need screen to return the session id or the PID to me so I record it in an array or a hash.

Comment: Are you talking about windows opened by your script or independently of your script?

Comment: opened by my script, so if I run `screen -d -m -s server1` I want screen to return to me something like `24031` which would be a pid, even if I could get it return back the entire session ID like `24031.server1` a little regex would solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your purpose for gathering these pids? It can be a little tricky in perl. Something like Unix::PID might help ( [http://metacpan.org/pod/Unix::PID](http://metacpan.org/pod/Unix%3a%3aPID) ) but I have the suspicion that your question does not address the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Since you are using `screen -dmS <somename>` you can do this:

```
my %screens;

for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  system("screen -dmS server$i");
}

open(my $fh, "screen -list|");
while (<$fh>){
  if (/Detached/) {
    /\s*(\d*)\.(.*?)\s/;
    my ($pid, $name) = ($1, $2);
    $screens{$name} = $pid;
  }
};
```

Comment: I need the pids in order to identify which screen I need to send commands to.

Comment: if you give your screens all uniquely identifiable names you can then collect the list from screen -list.

Comment: I am already using unique names. The reason I need the PIDs other than that is for killing the screens, the only way that works for me is to kill the process that my script spawned.

Comment: Right, so once you have your screens created, simply run a call to ``screen -list`` and will give you the list of screens as <pid>.<screenName>. Split that to create a hash of `$screen->{<name>} = <pid>;`

Comment: I have edited the original answer with some example code that creates 10 screens and then stores their PIDs in a hash array indexed by their names.

Comment: Are you able to kill the screens with the pids stored? On my server the pid of `screen -ls` did not correspond with that of something like `ps x`. Also have yuo verified that the screens were actually created? Once again on my server using the command `screen -dmS server01` not screens were actually created, but if I changed it to `screen -d -m -S server01` it worked fine, not sure why. I was thinking it could have something to do with Ubuntu but not sure what.

Comment: I did check that the screens were created and was able to access them. I simply exited them from there so I didn't bother trying to send commands to kill them. I was checking on a Fedora box so there may be a difference in how the builds of screen are handling the grouped switches, although that's surprising to me.

I also doubled checked the pids and they matched. Maybe there's something different in the Ubunto `screen -list` output that is interfering with the regex?

Comment: Ok I give your example a shot, looks like it should work well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the environment variable `$ENV{'STY'}` within any programs running *inside* `screen`.

On my MacOS X 10.6 system at least, it contains the session ID, e.g.:

```
29379.ttys000.hostname
```

and where the first field is the PID.

From *outside* `screen`, you can run:

```
screen -list
```

to get a list of all of your sessions.

Failing that, it's unclear how you're actually starting `screen` from within your script, but if you use a standard `fork / exec` model then the child PID available after the call to `fork` will be the required PID.  See `man perlipc` for more details on how to fork a child program and interact with it.

Comment: For right now I am calling `screen` via `system` just because I know it works. Later I may go back and use something better.